Maps on posets which preserve order in one of two ways
Let $(X,\leq)$ a countably infinite poset and $f:(X,\leq)\to (X,\leq)$ a map. I am looking for the term if $f$ satisfies for all $x,y\in X$ that if $x\leq y$ then $f(x)\leq f(y)$ or $f(y)\leq f(x)$. This is weaker than order preserving but $f$ preserves the fact that $x,y$ can be compared wrt $\leq$. So it is more than nothing.
Is there an established term for such $f$ ? And do they have interesting known properties?

Are you sure that you want "iff"?

@PaulTanenbaum I added the $\leq$ to the domain and codomain, to make clear that it is the same base set with the same ordering.

@PaulFrost no, that was a mistake, it should be an implication. Sorry for that.

I don’t know of a noun phrase meaning “any such function,” but you could certainly describe such a function as respecting comparability.

And a technicality: I suggested respecting comparability rather than preserving it because the former means essentially not breaking any existing comparabilities, while the latter means neither breaking existing ones nor creating new ones.
